# Swagger: skipping unknown type "dateTime"

Tags: node.js, swagger, loopbackjs, swagger-ui, loopback

I am getting below warning/error while specifying the data type for date and time in swagger spec for loopback. Below is my loopback `user.json` file

```
"properties": {
    "schedule": {
      "type": "dateTime",
      "required": true
    },
 }
```

> Swagger: skipping unknown type "dateTime"

Please may I know what is the relevant data type for date and time in swagger?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to declare a date in a OpenAPI / Swagger-file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379006/what-is-the-correct-way-to-declare-a-date-in-a-openapi-swagger-file)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specify the type as `string` and format as `date-time`:

"properties": {
        "schedule": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date-time",
          "required": true
        },
     }

[ https://swagger.io/specification/#dataTypes ]