# How to define dates like "Jan 22, 2020" in OpenAPI 2.0?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

At the moment I have:

```
type: string
format: YYYY-MM-DD
```

How can I match a date formatted like: `Jan 22, 2020`?

Is there a predefined way or I have to create a kind of regex?
Is it possible to use `pattern` instead of `format`?

Comment: Check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379006/what-is-the-correct-way-to-declare-a-date-in-an-openapi-swagger-file

Comment: @AshishKarn this question is about a different format of dates, so the answers in the linked Q&A don't apply here.

Answer (score 0):

I got an idea with regex, even tough is not matching it strictly:

```
type: string
pattern: '^[a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]+, [0-9]+$'
```