# OpenApi Spring Boot - Show date as yyyyMMdd

Tags: spring-boot, openapi

In my request model, I have a field like

```
@NotNull
@Schema(example = "19680228", type = "String", format = "yyyyMMdd", pattern = "([0-9]{4})(?:[0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})", required = true, nullable = false)
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
private OffsetDateTime birthDate;
```

My `birthday` is of `OffsetDateTime` type, however, request comming in contains only date portion in format yyyyMMdd.  This is requirement and cannot be changed.  And this is OK, I already take care of that with my `CustomDateDeserializer` and it is all working fine.

Based on OpenAPI documentation and some post (https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.3.md#data-types, [What is the correct way to declare a date in an OpenAPI / Swagger-file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379006/what-is-the-correct-way-to-declare-a-date-in-an-openapi-swagger-file)), I know that OpenAPI supports ISO8601 `date` and `date-time`, in which case, no `pattern` is needed and type should be provided as `date` or `date-time`.

However, in case you require some other format due to legacy code or no ability to change, the documentation states that `type` should be `String`, `format` should specify which format the date is in, and `pattern` should be provided as regex.

And this is exactly what I am doing in the above `@Schema` annotation.

However, when I go to https://editor.swagger.io/ and paste my .**yaml** file into it, the API generated for both my request model and my controller still contain incorrect formatting for `birthdate` and the `example` is not even taken into consideration:

Here is how it shows in my model:
[image]

As you can see, the `format` is still getting the format for `OffsetDateTime` and there is no example at all.

Same for my controller:

[image]

How do I make birthday show up as `yyyyMMdd`?  For example, how to make it show as `19720226` in swagger editor?

I am using OpenApi/Swagger 3 in a Spring Boot application.

Comment: I hope you have seen this https://xml2rfc.tools.ietf.org/public/rfc/html/rfc3339.html#anchor14
Why do you want to enforfce the time  to be in that specified format? was it business requirement?

Comment: Read please, 1st and 3rd paragraph